Time complexity of LALR construction
According to the dragon book, the algorithm for LR(1) state machine is:
initialize C to Closure([S` -> .S, $])
repeat
    for each state in C
        for each grammar symbol X
            if Goto(state, X) is not empty and is not in C
                add Goto(state, X) to C
until no new states are added

How can the time complexity of this algorithm can be analysed, in terms of the number of terminals, non-terminals and productions in the grammar.
Also, assuming this algorithm is changed to construct LALR(1) (such that a state is considered in C if there is a state with the same kernel), only the function in C changes (but not in terms of complexity). So how can their run times be expressed differently mathematically?
I know Closure is O(n * k) where:

n - number of terminals
k - number of production rules

(Obviously this bound is the very worst case and the average bound is probably lower)
But how can the complexity of the repeat until no new states are added be analysed?

It can depend entirely on how that step is implemented. In 1987 I found that  state set membership testing as implemented in yacc at that date was O(N^2). That’s not a property of the algorithm itself.

What I was trying to i say is that both LR and LALR construction are based on this algorithm, but obviously the LALR construction finished adding new states much earlier in terms of total states number. so how can that difference be expressed in time complexity? That is, given a LALR grammar, what is the number of states as function of grammar size?

Its probably easier to think in terms of the total "size" of the grammar -- the number of symbols used to express it, rather than the number of productions and the number of terminals/non-terminals.  This can be use to find a bound on the number of possible states.

How is it different?

If this isn't a student or theory exercise, you might not care.  We built our own LALR state table generator for use by our DMS commercial product.   Its a transliteration of  one I built 40 years ago on an 8 bit computer; it was not exactly optimized for speed.   On modern machines it runs in a few seconds on a variety of grammars with average size of 3000-5000 grammar rules.   Way fast enough for production development running it many times a day when engineering a grammar.

Well, it is a theory exercise... What I'm really trying to figure out here is how can the difference between LR and LALR be expressed in the time complexity? since they both use the almost same algorithm, but LALR main loop will end earlier (in terms of number of states, so also in terms of number of steps)

Is there a known relation between the size of the grammar and the number of states in the LALR state machine?
